# Dynamics CRM auto create relationship

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

Within Dynamics CRM 2011 online I have created an entity (called "Funding") which is a child of the Account entity (one to many). I have created the one to many and many to one relationships between the two and created a "regarding" field within Funding which links back to an Account.

What currently happens is when I create an instance of a Funding entity, the "regarding" field doesn't automatically populate and so the Funding instance is visible within all Accounts (from the Funding table within the Account form).

I would like the Funding entity to behave the same as the Activity entity does with regard to the Account (i.e. when you create an Activity within the Account form, it is automatically associated with that Account). I have tried creating a workflow to do this but I can't see how I can find the appropriate Account to relate without already having this link set up (and thus negating the need to do it)

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create two separate relationships?

Comment: Hi James, I did, I created one to many from account to funding and many to one from funding to account. I can create a funding instance from an account's form but it is then visible from all accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Field Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334512.aspx).

Concise setup steps be found here: http://www.pardot.com/faqs/ms-dynamics/mapping-your-mscrm-lead-fields-to-contact-fields/

In short, map the Account to the funding so creating a "funding" record from the context of an account pre-populates the field for you.

It is worth noting this will not apply for programmatic creation of records through the API, but will work for any users using the default forms.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I was conscious I may have to get my hands dirty to do this. I have found a workaround in the mean time - if you select "Funding" on the left toolbar under the list "common" entities when in the Account form, it creates a new instance with the regarding field pre-populated.